# Accessing k8s pods using ingress externally (outside k8s cluster) is better than accessing k8s pods using service within the cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, cassandra, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I did a Performance test where I do Writes/ Reads into/from DB (cassandra pods).
I perfrommed read/write ops on k8s pods (Cassandra) through Ingress from a external machine (outside k8s cluster). Similarly I also tried accessing same cassandra pods from another k8s pod using service with in the same cluster.
Surprisingly I could see the performance (in terms of latency) was better when i accessed via ingress!
Why accessing within the cluster via service is taking more time compared to ingress ?
Please let me know why this happens !

Thanks

Comment: which ingress you are using ? there could be chances ingress using some caching so first response is little slow and after that it's caching hops or counts, i have seen this type of perfomance with KONG api gateway.

Comment: while in service to service there could be chances your both pods on different nodes which will increase the hops for requests and due to that it's taking little longer, however i doubt not much difference will be there. i would recommand sharing numbers also so other can get idea also.

Comment: Reg Pt1: hi Harsh, Are there any references to understand more on this part "there could be chances ingress using some caching so first response is little slow and after that it's caching hops or counts". Also are you asking about ingress version that I am using ?

Comment: https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/proxy-cache/

Comment: Reg Pt2: I am writing 1 lakh records in to db. I could see a difference of some 2-3 mins between acessing via ingress and accessing via service. Ingress performs better!

Comment: Also any references to understand better on this? "while in service to service there could be chances your both pods on different nodes which will increase the hops for requests and due to that it's taking little longer"

Comment: https://www.learnsteps.com/how-exactly-kube-proxy-works-basics-on-kubernetes/

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.